# How to get device's "Is Reboot Required" property via .NET or WMI

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, device

I can't find this property neither in WMI and Registry ,

Where can I get this property?

[image: image here]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use WMI. For example Win32_Keyboard class contains ConfigurationManagerErrorCode field. This field has many values but one of them looks like what you need:

"14 (0xE) Device cannot work properly until the computer is restarted."

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx